# Rclone+Python - Retain the file permissions during the backup to the S3 bucket

Tags: python, rclone

I'm using the rclone with python. I want to persist the file permissions during the file transfer and then retain back during the restore.
What is the best way to implement this?

I don't see the "rclone mount" is the best solution for our transfer. Please suggest me...

Answer (score 0):

Different file systems have different scheme for storing permissions.
S3 uses ACL(access control list) based file permissions management which may be different to your local file system.
It may be difficult or impossible to fully preserve original file permissions.

compressing files into an archive is always the safest option when transfering data online:
`tar cf [File_name.tar] [Directory/Folder to Archive]`

alternatively, use another service on aws which may provide compatible file system to be used depending on your needs like EC2, EBS or AWS Backup.